# How to repeatedly loop through divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which changes the div display property on click on Next or Previous buttons. I am able to click on Next and see the next div or click on Previous to see the previous one; however, once it reaches to the end the classList becomes undefined or null. What I want to do is, when the page is loaded for the firs time, I want the user to click on Next until the end and then to the first div like in a loop. Also, if the user clicks on Previous from the first page, then I would want the user to see the last div. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Below is the code..

```js
var yogNumber = 0;
var yogs = document.querySelectorAll('.yog');

function next() {
  yogNumber++;
  if (yogs.length > yogNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogNumber].classList.add('active');
  }

}

function previous() {
  yogNumber--;
  if (yogs.length > yogNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogNumber].classList.add('active');
  }

}
```

```css
.yog {
  display: none
}
.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="yog active">
  <div id="heading">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 4</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="left" onclick="previous()">
  <</div>
    <br />
    <div id="right" onclick="next()">></div>
```

The error which I am getting at the moment is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined".

Comment: Use modulo operator `%` to get the next element in circular fashion.

Comment: The problem is the conditions used in next and prev operations

Comment: FYI your HTML is broken - you need to use the character entities for `>` and `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below.

```js
var yogNumber = 0;
var yogs = document.querySelectorAll('.yog');

function next() {
  yogNumber++;
  if (yogs.length > yogNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogNumber].classList.add('active');
  }
  else{
    yogNumber=0;
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogNumber].classList.add('active');
    }

}

function previous() {
  yogNumber--;
  if(yogNumber<0)
    {
      document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogs.length-1].classList.add('active');
      yogNumber=yogs.length-1;
      }
  else if (yogs.length > yogNumber) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    yogs[yogNumber].classList.add('active');
  }

}
```

```css
.yog {
  display: none
}
.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="yog active">
  <div id="heading">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 4</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="left" onclick="previous()">
  <</div>
    <br />
    <div id="right" onclick="next()">></div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an else clause and set the yogNumber to 0 if the length has reached last yog. i.e.

```
        function next(){
          yogNumber++;
          if(yogs.length>yogNumber)
          {
            activateDiv(yogNumber);
          }else{
            yogNumber = 0;
           activateDiv(yogNumber);

          }
        }
```

And I would extract the logic for making a div active to a function i.e.

```
function activateDiv(var divNumber){
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
  yogs[divNumber].classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('yog'),
    yog = 0;

function next(){
    yog++;

    if(yog < divs.length)
        yog = 0;
}
```

If yog is more than divs.length then set the yog to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop on divs. You can use `.next` and `.prev` to do it.

#### Sample

```js
function next() {
  var d = $(".yog.active");
  if (d.next().hasClass("yog"))
    d.removeClass("active")
    .next()
    .addClass("active");
}

function previous() {
  var d = $(".yog.active");
  if (d.prev().hasClass("yog"))
    d.removeClass("active")
    .prev()
    .addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.yog {
  display: none
}
.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yog active">
  <div id="heading">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="yog">
  <div id="heading">Text 4</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="left" onclick="previous()">
  < </div>
    <br />
    <div id="right" onclick="next()">></div>
```